# SQL Multi User Type Database

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database

I need a Database to store the following information :

**User :** FirstName, LastName, Email, Mobile, About/Description, Type (Staff/Freelancer/Client)

**Staff :** Type (Designer/FE Developer/BE Developer/DB Developer/SE Optimist), Rank of Staff
        (Manager/Staff/Employee), Projects worked on, Active Projects working on, Address, 
        Skills (HTML/CSS/JS/ASPX/PHP/DB Development/SEO/Design), 
        Software(Photoshop/Illustrator/In-Design/Fireworks/VisualStudio/MSQL/Wordpress)

**Freelancer :** Type (Designer/FE Developer/BE Developer/DB Developer/SE Optimist), Projects worked on, Active Projects working on, Address, Skills (HTML/CSS/JS/ASPX/PHP/DB Development/SEO/Design), Software (Photoshop/Illustrator/InDesign/Fireworks/VisualStudio/MSQL/Wordpress)

**Client :** Projects Owned, Active Projects owned, Address (Home/Work/Invoicing/Delivery)

**Address :** House No:, Street Address, Line 2, Line 3, County, Country, Postcode, Landline

**Project :** Title, Client Name, Start Date, End Date, Due Date, Status (Active, Hold, NotActive), About, Development Team (List of Freelancers or Staff working on the Project), Progress (done by Milestones : Design/FE/BE/DB/BO/SEO/Deployment)

Basically the thing I'm struggling on is how to link the different type of Address and Users etc. For example a User can be : Staff or a Freelancer or an Client, Or a staff or freelancer can also be a client. I have no idea how that would work in Database Format. The same goes for Address Types etc.

Any Help ? I'm really Stuck. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could have an "Attribute" table that spells out all the applicable types for the User; for example if a record in this table is for User ID 1, it might list multiple types which describe that user, like a Staff or Freelancer or Client type, each with its own unique type ID.

Comment: please review the e/r Diagram : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design#ER_Diagram_.28Entity-relationship_model.29

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about the basics of RDBMS design. It's sometimes called Entity-Relationship design.  It's a big topic. You may want to read a book on it.

It sounds like you need a Person table with a row describing each unique person in your system.

You then need, perhaps, an Organization table with a row describing each organization (company, consultancy, freelance entity, customer, provider, etc).

A Person_Organization table could relate persons to organizations.  This would implement a many-to-many entity relationship between Person and Organization. This table could contain PersonID, OrganizationID, and a field describing that person's role in that organization.

You could add a Contact table with contact information (addresses, tel nos, email, etc). It would contain a Person id in each row.

You'd have Project table with a row for each project.  This would contain an OrganizationID that identified the single customer for it, as well as other material describing the project.

There'd also be a Role table with a role for each Organization playing a role in each project.

How to handle an Organization that has more than one contact address is an exercise left to you.

Please keep in mind that "too clever is dumb" in this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

You do all of this using the concept of a foreign key.

Generally, a good idea is to give each table a primary key column that will serve as an identifier for each row of data. User table would have UserId, Project table would have ProjectId, etc.

From there, you add foreign key constraints to columns in your other tables that forces those rows to map to a User. For example, your Address table would have a column called UserId that is foreign key to the User table; this key tells you that the address of that row belongs to the corresponding User.

How to build the foreign key constraints depends on your requirements and the relationships between your data; it's something that you should figure out so that you will be able to access all of the necessary information using simple queries.

Also, keep in mind that your data is hierarchical. You have a Client, Freelancer, and Staff, each of which needs an address. But all of these 3 are also users. It makes much more sense to key each of those tables to the User table, and then key the Address table to the User table as well. This allows for your relationships to be more flexible and easier to understand.